# virtualenvwrapper hooks aren't loading automatically

Tags: python, hook, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

(Following Marina Mele's taskbuster Django tutorial)

The virtualenv is called tb_test. In $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/ (~/.virtualenvs/tb_test) I pasted the postactivate file from the general hooks folder in $WORKON_HOME and added 2 lines so now it looks like this:

**$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/postactivate**
    #!/bin/zsh
    # This hook is sourced after every virtualenv is activated.

```
echo "hELo"
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="taskbuster.settings.testing"
```

However, upon running `workon tb_test` the virtualenv gets activated and everything but the postactivate hook is not being loaded. No "heLo" echo :-(

Answer (score 1):

Works for me. Double check that you are using `workon` to activate the virtualenv (not `source bin/activate`), and that you are really activating the right virtualenv.

If it still does not work, please provide more information about your environment (OS, versions of involved packages, etc.). Did you modify any of the other virtualenv-wrapper hooks?

Update:
Maybe you created the hook in the wrong path? If you create the virtualenv with `mkvirtualenv`, it should create the `postactivate` file for you in the right place, so you just have to edit it. It should be in this location:

```
~/.virtualenvs/tb_test/bin/postactivate
```

To clarify: *not* in `~/.virtualenvs/tb_test/postactivate`

Comment: Yep using `workon` on the right virtualenv... I `mkvirtualenv`'d a couple other test virtualenvs and none of them had any hooks in $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin, not `postactivate`, not `predeactivate`... So that is not normal, I see? Would you happen to know why?

Comment: AFAIK, that is indeed not normal. Which version of virtualenv and virtualenv-wrapper are you using? Which OS/distro?

Comment: Mac OS X 10.9.5, virtualenv (12.0.7), virtualenvwrapper (4.3.2)

Comment: I'm not a Maccie, so I cannot test this on an a recent OS X system, sorry. I do get the hooks here on Linux. I hope somebody else can chime in and solve this.

Comment: It does! The right directory is the one right above the /bin folder and right below .virtualenvs right? Thanks for your help... I hope so too!

Comment: I think I've solved it. Let me know if the rehash tip works.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since this question was posted but now with Mac OS Catalina in more devices, ZSH comes as the default shell.

Well, I was having the same issue, couldn't activate environment variables.

What did the work was following the tips here: [VirtualEnvWrapper Tips](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tips.html)

In there, one of the tips suggest to add a `rehash` command after doing `echo $variables`. and did the trick.

Here are my `postactivate` or `preactivate` files in case:

```
### ~/.virtualenvs/MY_ENV/bin/post(pre)activate ###  
echo 'export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=MY_SETTINGS' >> ~/.zshenv
echo 'export SECRET_KEY=MY_SECRET' >> ~/.zshenv
echo rehash
```

Same for the `postdeactivate` and or `predeactivate`

It took me a while to find this tip, so hopefully this helps another helpless developer.